# Как получить username из формы Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть некая онлайн игра, которая для авторизации требует, чтобы пароль был хеширован в MD5 в порядке username + password. Как получить username из формы для использования его в хешировании?

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import AdvUser
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
from .models import user_registrated


class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Адрес электронной почты')
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль (повторно)', widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text='Введите тот же самый пароль еще раз для проверки')
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    # Валидация пароля 
    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1

    # Проверка на совпадение паролей, после валидации
    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError ('Введенные пароли не совпадают', code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.is_activated = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        user_registrated.send(RegisterUserForm, instance=user)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = AdvUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    ...
```

Comment: Это в forms.py надо писать или можно во views.py ? А то я хочу реализовать поиск в своём приложении, мне надо получить значение , которое юзер ввёл в форму и потом делать Good.objects.filter(height = {то, что ввёл пользователь})

Comment: Это никак не связано с вопросом, который был задан.

Comment: @Alex если у вас появился новый вопрос, то лучше [задать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) его отдельно)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086814/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8e%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8