# Как взять данные, введённые юзером, из формы и выполнить запрос к бд по ним? При этом не изменяя базу данных

Tags: python, django, orm, ui

**Есть пародия товаров в бд. Надо выполнить запрос по введённым параметрам и вывести их.**

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Good(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    diameter = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***forms.py***

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from goods.models import Good

def check_for_positive(value):
    if value < 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('NEEDS TO BE GREATER THEAN 0!')

class DoubleCheck(forms.ModelForm):
    # Form Fields go here
    class Meta:
        model = Good
        exclude = ['name'] # Exclude name
```

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from goods.models import Good
from . import forms

# Create your views here.
def search(request):
    form = forms.DoubleCheck
    form_dict = {'form':form,
                'result':False}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.DoubleCheck(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print('VALIDATION SUCCESS!')
            result = str(Good.objects.all().filter(height = {ТО ЧТО ВВЁЛ ЮЗЕР}, width = {ТО ЧТО ВВЁЛ ЮЗЕР}, diameter = {ТО ЧТО ВВЁЛ ЮЗЕР}))
            form_dict['result'] = result

    return render(request, 'goods/search.html', context = form_dict)
```

***search.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
            <p class="lead">Input parametres to see a list of relative goods</p>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <form method="POST">
                {{form.as_ul}}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            </form>

            {% if result %}
                <h3><em>Result: {{result}}</em></h3>                

            {% endif %}             


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во views.py с формы можно прочитать значения введенные пользователем так

```
def search(request):
form = forms.DoubleCheck
form_dict = {'form':form,
            'result':False}

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.DoubleCheck(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('VALIDATION SUCCESS!')
        height_user = form.cleaned_data.get("height")
        width_user = form.cleaned_data.get("width")
        diameter_user = form.cleaned_data.get("diameter")
        result = str(Good.objects.all().filter(height = height_user, width = width_user, diameter = diameter_user))
        form_dict['result'] = result

return render(request, 'goods/search.html', context = form_dict)
```